# How to get more information about the buffer cache

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, virtualization, qemu, kvm

I am using kvm, and I want to benchmark nested page tables with 2MB (huge page) hyervisor page size. It can be done in linux with hugetlbfs, where 2MB pages belong to a filesystem, and the application can then mmap from this filesystem and be sure that its actually using a 2MB page.

So, in qemu kvm, by running qemu with argument -mem-path /path, qemu will start using a 2MB page.

I want to make sure that this indeed my guest operating system is backed by 2 MB physical huge page.

I am using 12G physical memory for the guest.

So this is probably how the control should flow.. When the guest uses some page for the 1st time, it will take a page fault in the guest and in the hypervisor, a 2MB page should be mapped by the host(hypervisor). This 2MB page is backed by hugetlbfs, hence it should be a part of buffer cache.. Am i right?

So is there a way where i can get more information about buffer cache and see how many pages of different filesystems are in the buffer cache?

Its important for me, because I want to benchmark 2MB page in hypervisor with 4KB page in hypervisor, and I dont want the page faults in hypervisor to have an effect in my measurements. So, I want to get all the hypervisor pages in physical memory for both the cases and then start my benchmarking.

Thanks